# What do # and ## operators do in C?

Tags: c

something like #NAME or ##NAME. what do they mean in C? I saw them in GCC documents about macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

operator ## concatenates two arguments leaving no blank spaces between them..

```
 #define printe(a,b) a ## b
   printe(c,out) << "testing";
```

output is : testing

and single # is used for parameter replacement withe the string parameter
like

```
#define  st(x)  #x
 cout<<st(tesing); //  equivalent to  cout<<"testing";
```

and # is also a preprocessor directive..

Answer (score 1):

From the wikipedia page describing the [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation):

> The ## operator concatenates two tokens into one token, as in this example:

```
#define DECLARE_STRUCT_TYPE(name) typedef struct name##_s name##_t
DECLARE_STRUCT_TYPE(g_object); // Outputs typedef struct g_object_s g_object_t;
```

The `#` operator signals other directives to the C preprocessor, for example: `#include, #define, #undef, #error, #if, #ifdef, #ifndef, #else, #elif, #endif`

Comment: How about the single #? And are these two operators only be used in Macros?

Comment: @user1229490 I updated my answer. Yes, they're used only in the C and C++ macro preprocessor

Answer (score 1):

A code statement beginning with `#` indicates what follows is a preprocessor directive and should be expanded by the pre-processor.

`##` is called token ***[Pasting or Token concatenation macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html)***.

Answer (score 0):

The '#' is really not an operator, they are preprocessor directives, and the '##' is used only for function macro definitions.

---

There are many preprocessor directives in C:

For Macro Definitions there are:

```
#define
#undef
```

For Conditional Inclusions, there are:

```
#ifdef
#ifndef
#if
#endif
#else
#elif
```

For Line Control, there is:

```
#line
```

For Error, there is:

```
#error
```

For Source file inclusion, there is:

```
#include
```

For Pragma directive, there is:

```
#pragma
```

---

For more information, read this http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/