# Does the # symbol have any definition in C?

Tags: c, macros, keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do # and ## operators do in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843777/what-do-and-operators-do-in-c)

I can't seem to word the proper google query for this question so I'll decided to ask you wonderful people.

I've seen # being used in macro definitions, but what the hell does it mean?

Reference: http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Faking_Templates_In_C.shtml

That begs a secondary question, are templates in C++ implemented using macros?

Comment: As for the C++ part: no, not at all.

Comment: `hash` is a common term for `#`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the GCC documentation on the [`cpp` preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). The `#` sign is used for [stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) of macro arguments, and the double `##` for [concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html)

C++ templates are not implemented as preprocessor textual macros. You might feel them as being macros producing [abstract syntax trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (of some core subset of C++).

FYI, [Common Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_lisp) has an even more powerful macro system.

Answer (score 0):

`##` concats two tokens together, in the case of `type##_InitVector`, the content `type` with `_InitVector`.